# C programming, access char in a string with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

If I have this code block

```
char *array[] = {"element1" , "eLement2"};
char *p ;
char *pc;
```

How can I point `*p` to the first String `"element 1"` and 
how can I point `*pc` to the second character of the second String `L`
and then print those two using printf

Comment: `p=array[0];pc=&array[1][1];printf("%s, %c\n", p, *pc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p = array[0]
pc = array[1]+1

This should do the trick